# Found a weird piece of lab equipment?

Tags: terminology

My physics teacher found a weird piece of equipment in his classroom that was dated to the 70's. The item in question has no identifying marker except for "Carolina Biological". He has contacted the company and they told him it was a ring launcher. However, if this were a ring launcher, it does not explain the additional appendages on the said equipment.

Because it is so old, the catalogues from Carolina Biological are inaccessible, and we are hoping to learn of what exactly this was.

I have uploaded an image here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hQ3h.jpg

Any sort of help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: If it were a launcher, the electromagnet should be at the bottom. Looks to me like it is designed to levitate metallic objects instead.

Comment: Your teacher found what's known as _Einstein's Bong_.